# Why Command Prompt and calculator gives different answer?

Tags: java, calculator, command-prompt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4fAZ.png)I'm learning how those arithmetic operation and using notepad and command prompt and checking those if its right at my phone's calculator and laptops calculator and it gives different answer . I'm using java language

I've tried computing it manually

Int x =12;
float y = 13.54f;

System.out.println(x/y+" devide 12 - 13.54");//0.88691795 on my calcu i get  0.886262924667...

Comment: how can we even guess without seeing your code?

Comment: You'll have to be more specific.  What calculation did you try?  What result did the command prompt give you?  What about your Java program?  May we see your Java program?

Comment: You seem to have mentioned three calculators here; phone, laptop and "notepad and command prompt". None of those is (in and of itself) a calculator. You also mention that you have tried computing "it" manually. What is **it**? What answers are you getting?

Comment: int x = 12;
float y = 13.53f;
System.out.println(x+y +" Add 12 - 13.54");//25.529999
System.out.println(x-y +" minus 12 - 13.54");//-1.5299997
System.out.println(x/y+" devide 12 - 13.54");//0.88691795 on my calcu i get  0.886262924667...
System.out.println(x%y+" remaider or modulus 12 - 13.54");//12.0
System.out.println(x*y+ " multiplication 12 - 13.54");//162.36
System.out.println(x-y + " minus 12 - 13.54");//-1.5299997

++x;
--y;
System.out.println(y);
System.out.println(x);



/////////////////// the division part

Comment: Simple...you need to decide what `y` is going to be.... `13.53` or will it be `13.54`?

Comment: Kristine - your command window shows `y = 13.53`.  Your code shows `y = 13.54`.  I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: ohh my goshh sorry i didn't notice im sosoryy...

Comment: thanks for answering im sorry i trouble you guys ... buy just a single number Thank you and sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TL;DR: Unable to reproduce.*

From question:

> I've tried computing it manually
>
> Int x =12;
>   float y = 13.54f;
>
> System.out.println(x/y+" devide 12 - 13.54");//0.88691795 on my calcu i get  0.886262924667...

I don't know where you get 0.88691795
When I run your code, I get 0.88626295

Here is extended version of your code, with output:

```
int x = 12;
float y = 13.54f;
double z = 13.54;
System.out.println(x/y + "         using float math");
System.out.println(x/z + " using double math");
System.out.println("0.886262924667...  using calcu");
```

```
0.88626295         using float math
0.8862629246676514 using double math
0.886262924667...  using calcu
```

As you can see, none of it gives the result you claim to get. Please try again.

Comment: Andreas i add a photo link . thanks for response but my command prompt didn't answer as the same as yours

Comment: thanks for answering im sorry i trouble you guys ... buy just a single number Thank you and sorry